# Costly File Modification Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

Sadly, when I was very new, I misunderstood what CORE was and downloaded 18, 20, and 22 on my desktop.  As I grew more knowledgeable, I realized they were for IoT applications and NOT my desktop.  I opened the SNAP software store and found them as installed in the "system" portion of the display, with no "uninstall" option available.

My next action was to actually find the 3 file folders and try and delete them manually.  I was not allowed to do this.  However, I could change the folder names.  I figured if I changed them, if they are not being used they would just be passed over during machine start up.  Core18 became 18, Core20 became 20, and Core22 became 22, through manual folder name changes.

When I restarted the computer, I lost the ability to open any software I had installed through the SNAP store, and in fact can not open the SNAP store itself.  In all cases, I click, I get the busy circle for a few seconds and then the process ends.  As near as I can see, all of the software I installed is still there, it just does not open.

The file folders I changed to 18,20, and 22 are still there, but they appear empty.  New folders are also now present that are labeled Core18, Core20, and Core22, just like the originals.  I no longer have the ability to rename any file folders in the SNAP folder.

I'm sure new nitwits do dumb things all the time and I got a bit paranoid over CORE being on my machine.

Any advice on making the SNAP store run again, along with the software would be appreciated, even if it is paid for support.  I've got a 1TB drive and the thought of a clean install and manual recovery is saddening.

```
------------SNAP LIST------------
merlin@merlin-Dell-DM055:~$ snap list
Name                         Version              Rev    Tracking         Publisher          Notes
audacity                     3.1.3                1051   latest/stable    lucyllewy✪         -
bare                         1.0                  5      latest/stable    canonical✓         base
core18                       20231027             2812   latest/stable    canonical✓         base
core20                       20240111             2182   latest/stable    canonical✓         base
core22                       20240111             1122   latest/stable    canonical✓         base
cups                         2.4.7-3              1024   latest/stable    openprinting✓      -
gnome-3-34-1804              0+git.3556cb3        93     latest/stable/…  canonical✓         -
gnome-3-38-2004              0+git.efb213a        143    latest/stable    canonical✓         -
gnome-42-2204                0+git.ff35a85        141    latest/stable    canonical✓         -
gtk-common-themes            0.1-81-g442e511      1535   latest/stable/…  canonical✓         -
kf5-5-110-qt-5-15-11-core22  5.110                3      latest/stable    kde✓               -
kolourpaint                  23.08.4              104    latest/stable    kde✓               -
riseup-vpn                   0.21.11-14-gb798364  179    latest/stable    leapsnaps          classic
signal-desktop               7.0.0                630    latest/stable    snapcrafters✪      -
snap-store                   41.3-71-g709398e     959    latest/stable    canonical✓         -
snapd                        2.61.2               21184  latest/stable    canonical✓         snapd
telegram-desktop             4.15.0               5581   latest/stable    telegram-desktop✓  -
zoom-client                  5.17.10.3512         225    latest/stable    ogra               -
merlin@merlin-Dell-DM055:~$
```

Comment: You should actually leave those snaps alone, since they are required for other snaps to work...

Comment: Obviously true.  My ignorance may be costly.  Thank You for your input.

Comment: There should be a possibility to "Repair Ubuntu" using the Live USB installer, or to smply install on top of an existing installation. But I'm not an expert on desktop flavors etc.

Comment: I have my original installation CD available.

Comment: There should be some option to repair or reinstall with data intact if you boot that, if I'm not mistaken (I'm trying to get that confirmed by someone who knows more about desktop installs).

Comment: Thank You Artur.  I am running a backup computer, so I can take my time and not do something stupid by being in too much of a hurry.

Comment: Does the `snap` command work? Test by running `snap list`. If it doesn't work, then copy the complete output and post it in your question above.

Comment: I added the SNAP list above.  I also tried to associate the three gnome files with the snap store as suggested in another spot.  gnome3-34-1804 and gnome3-38-2004 returned errors.  gnome42-2004 did not return an error, however snap store functionality has not been restored.

Comment: merlin@merlin-Dell-DM055:~$ snap refresh snap-store
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "snap-store" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot locate base snap core22: No such file or directory)

Comment: See above.  I manually refreshed the snaps in terminal, but the snap store seems to be missing the hook to core22.

Comment: Core22 does exist in the top level snap folder.  A refresh said it was up to date.

Comment: After a large amount of plinking around on the keyboard, I have determined the following: Snap-store is installed and was refreshed.  Core22 is installed and was refreshed.  When trying to install snap-store it consistently says it can not find core22.  Also, snap-store is no longer listed in the snap list.

Comment: CASE CLOSED and left in case someone else needs this trail of info.  When I manipulated the CORE22 file folder, the program was given an alias name by the operating system, (I assume).  When I removed and re-installed CORE22 the situation resolved and I was then able to install snap-store again.